# I get this message when I open (most) games on my PC

Tags: windows, visual-c++, runtime

In the following picture is the message I get when I try to open (most) games on my computer. [error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9MXMP.png)

I have tried reinstalling drivers, using different versions of drivers, deleting and reinstalling all of the runtime packages from control panel, factory resetting my PC and nothing has worked. Any ideas?

Comment: Try downloading the runtime installer from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/latest-supported-vc-redist?view=msvc-170 If it won't install then perhaps your antivirus is interfering or there is something wrong with your Windows installation.